# Convert value in string into hashmap?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a string where i have multiple values. The key and value are separated by `*` and the whole value is separated by `$`.

Below is the example:

```
String agf = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";
```

And now I want to put the value of this into hashmap in key value pair.

Below is the code i was using but didnt work for converting it into hashmap. Please guide.

```
String agf = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";

String []tmp = StringUtils.split(agf,'*');
for (String v : tmp) {
    String[] t = StringUtils.split(v,'$');
    map.put(t[0], t[1]);
}
```

Comment: Switch `*` and `$` in the arguments to `split`, then it's going to work.

Comment: are you sure you had only 1 value for a given key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parse{
    public static void main(String ...args){
        String agf = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";
        String [] split = agf.split("\\$");
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String temp : split){
            String [] tempo = temp.split("\\*");
            map.put(tempo[0],tempo[1]);
        }
        for(String mapkeys : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(mapkeys+" ::: "+map.get(mapkeys));
        }
    }
}
```

if you had multiple values for a given key then use this:

```
public static void main(String ...args){
        String agf = "abc*pqr*gas$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";
        String [] split = agf.split("\\$");
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String temp : split){
            String [] tempo = temp.split("\\*");
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
            for(int i = 1; i < tempo.length;i++){
                sj.add(tempo[i]);
            }
            String value = sj.toString();
            map.put(tempo[0],value);
        }
        for(String mapkeys : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(mapkeys+" ::: "+map.get(mapkeys));
        }
    }
```

Hope you found this helpful

Comment: If you had multiple values for given key please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example string, you should be splitting first on `$` (to get individual key value pairs) and then on `*` (to separate key and values)

Answer (score 0):

Switch '*' and '$'.

```
String agf = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";
String []tmp = StringUtils.split(agf,'$');
for (String v : tmp) {
   String[] t = StringUtils.split(v,'*');
   map.put(t[0], t[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use  `string.split("//$")` and `string.split("//*")` as regex for your use case.**

**Full code :**

```
        String str = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";
        String[] entries = str.split("\\$");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (int i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            String[] entry = entries[i].split("\\*");
            map.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }

        System.out.println("Entries are -> " + map.entrySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String agf = "abc*pqr$sfd*ghn$atr*mnb$tre*fgt";

\\next array will contain such elements: "abc*pqr", "sfd*ghn", "atr*mnb", "tre*fgt"
String[] pairs = agf.split("\\$");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();

for (String pair: pairs) {

    \\in first iteration next array will contain such elements: "abc", "pqr"
    String[] t = pair.split("\\*");

    \\just fill out map with data
    map.put(t[0], t[1]);
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @nithesh-kumar This is working, when I'm doing System.out.println(map); I have such output: {sfd=ghn, abc=pqr, tre=fgt, atr=mnb}